How to print a fill circle in console in java?
Is there way to print a fill circle to console?
I tried:
public class test0 {
    public static void circle(int posX, int posY, int rad) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= posX + rad; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= posY + rad; j++) {
                int xSquared = (i - posX) * (i - posX);
                int ySquared = (j - posY) * (j - posY);
                if (Math.abs(xSquared + ySquared - rad * rad) < rad) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        circle(5,10,5);
    }
}

I was expecting a fill circle but I got a hollow circle.

The condition if (Math.abs(xSquared + ySquared - rad * rad) < rad) checks if the point is on the perimeter. You should adjust it to check for all points within the circle like: if (xSquared + ySquared <= rad * rad).
So it should be:
public class test0 {
    public static void circle(int posX, int posY, int rad) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= posX + rad; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= posY + rad; j++) {
                int xSquared = (i - posX) * (i - posX);
                int ySquared = (j - posY) * (j - posY);
                if (xSquared + ySquared <= rad * rad) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        circle(5, 10, 5);
    }
}


You should try maybe :
 public static void circle(int posX, int posY, int rad) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= posX + rad; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= posY + rad; j++) {
                int xSquared = (i - posX) * (i - posX);
                int ySquared = (j - posY) * (j - posY);
                if (xSquared + ySquared <= rad * rad) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

